# Cannot resolve symbol ContextCompat - where to download android-support-v4.jar?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I am trying to update my app to request runtime permissions for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (with the latest Android release I am no longer able to access the /storage/emulated/0 folder).
The code below gives an error "Cannot resolve symbol ContextCompat", which from reading other threads here I understand requires that I add android-support-v4.jar to my project.

```
private boolean checkPermission() {

return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ;
}
```

The problem is that this library is not in my SDK folder, and is not listed in the SDK tools tab in Android Studio (v3.0.1). Can anyone tell me how/where I download this library so that it can be added to my project?

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 66
        versionName "3.22"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
//        debug {
//            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
//            debuggable true
//        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/logback-android-1.1.1-3.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to manually add jars. You use Gradle

Comment: I have this in my build.gradle file but it didn't help: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'

Comment: Is your compileSdk set to version 23?

Comment: Also, you don't even need to explicitly compile that if you're using appcompat-v7 or support-design dependencies

Comment: Yes it's set to 23.

Comment: These are the dependencies in build.gradle: compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/logback-android-1.1.1-3.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'

Comment: In the documentation, it says `com.android.support:support-compat` is the name of the artifact, but I think that's only for latest versions of Android

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that, not the comments

Comment: Ok I've put my full build.gradle file in the comments. Is there anything wrong with my reference to the support-v4 lib?

Comment: You have the right library, but your versions are *very* old. `23.1.0` came out in October 2015, nearly 2.5 years ago. `ContextCompat` was released in `22.1.0`, though, so you should have access to that class.